# extract the shapes made a particular colour in opencv

Tags: c++, c, opencv, image-segmentation, opencv3.0

take this image below

[image: source image]

I would like to extract the shapes of the red outline into a separate image. I want to do this because I want to check the convexity of theses shapes for my work. Any advice? I tried split channels but that just removes the red colour from the image.

Comment: how did you got these reds? Is this image an input for you?

Comment: nope..I did a contour drawing..What I ant basically is to get the outline of the dark area inside the image.So I did this thing.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have drawn the red border by yourself, there is no need to analyze the red component at all. By doing that, you are exactly like someone who take a print screen of txt file and trying to OCR it!

**The solution:**

1. `cv::BoundingBox` around the point of the first red contour.
2. Get `ROI` of the rectangle and store it in a separate `cv::Mat`.
3. Create a new black(`0`) `cv::Mat` with the same header of the previous cv::Mat.
4. Draw the contour with White(`255`) using `cv::fillPoly`.
5. `cv::bitwise_and` between the two `cv::Mats`.

Answer (score -1):

You could try making an image that comprises pixels where red is the dominant colour, for example you would examine every pixel and make a B/W image like this

```
#define MIN_RED     192
#define MAX_OTHER   64

// each pixel
if (r >= MIN_RED && g <= MAX_OTHER && b <= MAX_OTHER)
    c = 1;
else
    c = 0;
```

This would filter out the blues and greens and grays and preserve the bright reds.

Comment: can you be a little more specific. What is the variable 'c'?

Comment: It is to create a new image. In the answer I said "B/W image", which has only 2 colour values, hence the 1 and 0. If you prefer you can use pixel colour values with `r=255; g=255; b=255;` and `r=0; g=0; b=0;`